# The QUERY is giving double results on a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I recently started to use QUERYs on Google Sheets. I just encountered a problem where after typing my query

```
=QUERY('Copy of TEST'!A1:E7,"select A, sum(D) 
group by A")
```

it is compounding the A1 row with the Title of my columns (in this case is "Service Type Updates"), and the row A2 that belongs to the first service ("Consultation").

**Service Type Updates**  Consultations     **sum Tier 1**   1

I have tried everything adding an extra row between those to rows but nothing.

Comment: try: `=QUERY('Copy of TEST'!A1:E7,"select A, sum(D) 
group by A LABEL SUM(D)''")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try excluding the header row from the query, by starting the range with `A2` instead of `A1`:

```
=QUERY('Copy of TEST'!A2:E7,"select A, sum(D) group by A")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but now because I'm using sum(D) is bringing this result in the totals =: sum Tier 1 1.

Comment: Can you share what data you have in the table?